# Pull changes from a specific directory of the remote repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-pull, git-remote

I have a git repo (repoA) and I am trying to pull the files from a particular directory in the remote repo (repoB). How can I achieve this without pulling files from all the directories in repoB?

To describe this issue more, lets assume that we have a repoA and repoB. The directories in repoA are app, test, and data. Whereas in repoB, the files are app, test, data1, and data2. I am trying to pull the files from the test folder of repoB into repoA. Please guide on how to achieve this.

Comment: Generally speaking, `git pull` and related commands work with *commits*, not files; and a commit contains all the files in the repository at that point in history. It would be helpful to know more about the *underlying* aim here: are you trying to reduce the amount of data downloaded, or just ignore particular changes, or ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your remote repository `repoB` can be clone thougt `ssh` on the following address `git@gitlab.com:repos/repoB.git`. Then, to get only files from `test` directory of `repoB`:

- go to your `repoA`
- Fetch the other repo: `git fetch git@gitlab.com:repos/repoB.git`
- Then checkout them on your current branch: `git checkout FETCH_HEAD test`

All files from `test` directory of `repoB` are now added. You have just to commit them.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it might be worth stressing that unlike a `git pull`, this will not record any of the *history* of those files. It's effectively a way of *downloading* them. Also, any conflicts won't show up until you've committed and attempt to merge with another branch - the `git checkout` command will simply overwrite any local files, or abort if there are any *uncommitted* changes.

Comment: Good point indeed, I removed the part about the conflits. You can still `git reset .` + `git diff` to check the changed that imply, but it become to be complex move.